# Jquery draggable: How to restrict image moving horizontally

Tags: jquery-ui

I have done this using jquery draggable. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/hMmbK/2/)

```
$("img").draggable({ containment: [-99, -119, 0, 0], scroll: false });
```

How can I get the values of x, y of the visible portion of image.

I want to click and drag the image some times, when i move cursor, image is moving, i do not want this to happen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constrain the movement with the axis option.
    { axis: "y" }

Comment: If i have an div, which is of 295 * 92 and the image height is 165:If I drag the image, I see white area. I do not want to see white area, I should be only able to drag till the image is available.